# How to avoid p-dropdown from closing on body scroll apart from appendTo="body"

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, primeng

I am using Angular version 12 and PrimeNG version 12 for my project. For the same I am using primeng dropdown which gets closed on scrolling the body. Using appendTo="body" doesn't close the dropdown on scroll but moves the dropdown panel with it. Many people have faced this issue but I haven't found any workaround for it still.

```
<div class="customScroll">
  <p-dropdown
    filter="true"
    [options]="options" 
    [(ngModel)]="model" 
    (onChange)="filterTable()"
    [style]="{'width': '100%', 'margin-top': '10px', 'font-family': 'Roboto Regular'}"
  >
  </p-dropdown>
</div>
```

Comment: It's absolutely positioned when you use appendTo body. if they allow it open while scrolling the panel will be misplaced. thats why the close it.

Answer (score 4):

You can patch this by passing an `overlayOptions`

```
[overlayOptions]="getOverlayOptions()"
```

defined as:

```
getOverlayOptions(): OverlayOptions {
    return {
      listener: (event: Event, options?: OverlayListenerOptions) => {
        return false;
      }
    };
}
```

If anyone cares for the story behind this patch:
You will notice that when testing their components on their website it does not happen, I highly suspect someone is preventing scroll event propagation to hide a bug, as when I cloned their project and inside their own project I made a new container that has a scrollbar, the same unintended behavior occurs.
Anyway, upon further source inspection you will find a line that has a weird line regarding scroll listeners like:

```
x || y
```

where both have side effects, and the second one will only be executed if the first one returns something evaluated as false. I do not have time to give the exact files and line numbers as it was a rather long process of resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `appendTo="body"`  property of PrimeNG dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research around it but didn't found anything.

But this issue is fixed in the latest release of ngPrime which is 14.0.0